# SQL query: check if pd is the same across customer_id

Tags: sql

I have the following table with **customer_id, facility_id, and pd**

[image]

Please note that **customer_id** can have many **facility_id**. Also, each **customer_id** should have an unique **pd**.

Therefore, I would like to come across a query that checks that for each of the **customer_id** the **pd** is the same, taking in consideration that a customer may have many **facility_id**

Comment: Please tag only the **single** RDBMS of interest - not 4 different products!

Comment: I would suggest that a redesign of the database is in order here. Move the `pd` from this table and place it in the `customer` table. Then a customer can only ever have one

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. It can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about. I have removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] yoiur question and tag properly.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: What is the _type_ of the `pd` column, and are the "same" values really numerically the same, or are these values floats (which are not exact) ?

Comment: and what do you want as an outcome: list of customers with different pd or something other?

Comment: 2 tables is certainly what you want here; one for the customer (which has the `pd`), and another for the customer and facility relationship.

Comment: @Sergey indeed. I would like as an outcome the list of customers for which the PD is not same. For example, customer_id = 5542 has facility_id = [7895, 5485, 9582], however, it has pd = [0.12, 0.15, 0.12]. Please note that pd should be the same pd = [0.12, 0.12, 0.12]

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT X.CUSTOMER_ID
 FROM YOUR_TABLE AS X
 GROUP BY X.CUSTOMER_ID
 HAVING MIN(X.PD)<>MAX(X.PD)
```

List of customers with different PD